# How do I make bash's glob character classes case-sensitive?

Tags: bash, globbing

I had created some files like `knob_A.png` and `knob_a.png` and my teammate on Windows said this caused problems with her app.  I decided to call it `knob_W.png` instead of `knob_a.png`.  Then I did an rsync up to our shared server.  In order to clean things up I then did

```
rm knob_[a-d]*.png
```

and it removed `knob_A.png` too.  This is wrong as a football bat.

Neither `shopt -s nocaseglob` nor `shopt -u nocaseglob` causes it to behave the way I want.

How do I tell bash to make its globs be case-sensitive like in the old days?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash is being case sensitive here. The problem is with the sorting order of the characters in the range. From the Bash manual (`info bash`):

> The sorting order of characters in range expressions is determined by the current
>   locale and the value of the 'LC_COLLATE' shell variable, if set.
>
> For example, in the default C locale, '[a-dx-z]' is equivalent to
>   '[abcdxyz]'.  Many locales sort characters in dictionary order, and in
>   these locales '[a-dx-z]' is typically not equivalent to '[abcdxyz]';
>   it might be equivalent to '[aBbCcDdxXyYz]', for example.  To obtain
>   the traditional interpretation of ranges in bracket expressions, you
>   can force the use of the C locale by setting the 'LC_COLLATE' or
>   'LC_ALL' environment variable to the value 'C'.

**Try doing**

```
export LC_COLLATE=C
```

Comment: you might want to expand the shell example to: `LC_COLLATE=C; ls knob_[a-d]*.png` .  I'm used to doing things like `LC_COLLATE=C ls knob_[a-d]*.png` which does not work, probably because that only sets the environment of the subprocess and does not affect the bash that evaluated the glob.

Comment: @MutantBob is correct: bash expands the glob before it sets LC_COLLATE but the main problem is that a simple X=Y sets a local shell variable X, which is _not_ the same thing as an environment variable and LC_COLLATE is an environment variable.

Comment: To set an environment variable temporarily for one command, say:

`LC_COLLATE=C command`

Note: _no semicolon_ between the assignment and the command.

To set it for the rest of the session, say:

`export LC_COLLATE=C`

This will affect globs on subsequent lines.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has a shell option to preserve the pattern match so case isn't ignored during the expansion. You can add `shopt -s globasciiranges` to your script to enable case sensitive matches, and turn it off using `shopt -u globasciiranges`. See [Bash Reference - Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)

Alternatively you can use the `LC_COLLATE=C` as listed in the other answer, but make sure it has been exported to your environment with `export LC_COLLATE`